# .next in jQuery is not working

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<span class="open_download_link">
    <a>Downloads</a>
    <img src="layout/download.gif"/>
</span>
<div class="download_box">
    <img src="layout/icon_en.png" />
    <a target="_blank" href="products/pdf/modules_bp_3230Q_en.pdf">Datasheet download</a>
    <img src="layout/pdf.gif" />
    <a target="_blank" href="products/pdf/modules_bp_3230Q_en.pdf">pdf, 1.6 MB</a>
</div>
```

with this jQuery:

```
$('.open_download_link a, .open_download_link img').click(
    function () {
        $(this).next('div').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

I've been trying for hours with sibling, nextAll and other things, but nothing works.
I really don't get why!
Any ideas for what i could do to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're selecting an `a` *inside* the `span`. `.next()` will just find the `img` tag after the link and do stuff with that.

Try this, using [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) to select the `span` and *then* find the `div` after it:

```
$('.open_download_link a, .open_download_link img').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().next('div').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no next DIV in that tree. You need to go up the tree first.

Try: `$(this).parent().next('div').slideToggle('slow');`

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely at your HTML, you'll see that there is no `<div>` following the link or image. It's a sibling of the parent container, `.open_download_link`.

```
$('.open_download_link a, .open_download_link img').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().next('div').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The div you are trying to select is not a sibling of the clicable elements. Try this:

```
$('.open_download_link a, .open_download_link img').click(
    function () {
        $(this).closest('.open_download_link').next('div').slideToggle('slow');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
$('.open_download_link a, .open_download_link img').click(
    function () {
        $(this).parent().next('div').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

This will move up to the clicked elements parent (the 'open_download_link' span) `next` can then be used to find the sibling div of the span element.

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/CP99R/